# How to start activity to reopen the app in onStop?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to implement a function to reopen app shortly after it is minimized. The code is as follows:

```
private fun bringAppToFront(){
   Toast.makeText(this, "Reopening the app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
   val intentToReopenApp = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
   intentToReopenApp.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
   this.startActivity(intentToReopenApp)
}

override fun onStop() {
   Log.d(TAG, "On stop called")
   Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
       bringAppToFront()
   }, 1000)
   super.onStop()
}
```

However, after minimizing the app doesn't reopen, I only see the toast

Comment: Every app run on their own Process with unique id. And when user minimize the app that mean OS use app lifecycle instead of activity lifecycle. So you can't do it with above code. better you reopen the app

Comment: so how can I reopen the app in this case?